# Add the UsbSerialForAndroid library in application results in gradle error

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build an Android application using the UsbSerialForAndroid library, but I keep getting gradle error.

The recommended way to do so is to clone the library repository, and add it in the build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':usb-serial-for-android:usbSerialForAndroid')
}


A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Project with path ':usb-serial-for-android:UsbSerialForAndroid' could not be found in project ':app'.
```

Adding ':usb-serial-for-android' in the include in settings.gradle does not fix this, adding ':usb-serial-for-android:UsbSerialForAndroid' changes the error to

```
> Cannot evaluate module UsbSerialForAndroid : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Gradle saying «Configuration with name 'default' not found» means «I could not find the project»… Fixing the case mistake helps.

So the solution :

- clone the repository
- add in app/build.gradle, in dependencies : 
      compile project(':usb-serial-for-android:usbSerialForAndroid')
- add in settings.gradle :
  include ':usb-serial-for-android:usbSerialForAndroid', ':app'